# Choosing Python environment for Python execution in Openrefire

Tags: python, openrefine

I recently install Openrefine and it's great, especially enjoying the python execution option.
Within the python execution, one can import additional packages, this can be seen in this example where the random package is imported.

[Example of Openrefine python execution which returns random word out of the first 50 words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QqA0.png)

Now, I want to use a special package within the Openrefine tool, which is installed on one of my Conda environments. can I activate a particular Conda env that will be executed in Openrefine tool?

Answer (score 1):

> TL;DR: just wrap your Python package with FastAPI and communicate via HTTP requests.

### OpenRefine and Jython

OpenRefine is using [Jython](https://www.jython.org/), a Java implementation of Python.
Therefore, you can not "just" activate a conda environment, but you have to provide a Jython compatible package.

There is a tutorial in the OpenRefine wiki describing [how to extend Jython with PyPi modules](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Extending-Jython-with-pypi-modules).

Please note that currently 2.7 is the newest Jython implementation. Jython 3 is still in it's planing and development phase. See [Jython 3 Roadmap](https://www.jython.org/jython-3-roadmap) for details. This makes it difficult to use external libraries, as Python 2 had its end of life on 01.01.2020 and accordingly (most) libraries stopped supporting Python 2.

Also, some Python packages rely on C libraries that are not compatible with Jython. Check the [Appendix A of the Definitive Guide to Jython](https://jython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/appendixA/) for more details on using external tools and libraries.

### Alternative solution using FastAPI

Personally I find it easier to just wrap the Python packages I want to use with [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) and communicate from OpenRefine via HTTP requests. Depending on your data you can then [add new columns by fetching URLs](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/columnediting#add-column-by-fetching-urls) or use [GET/POST requests in Jython](https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/fetch-and-parse-data-with-openrefine#jython-get-request).

I recently created a GitHub Gist showing how to [wrap the NER component of a spaCy model with FastAPI](https://gist.github.com/b2m/6e2697ce182548a98320e4b7b7b885b6) to be then used via OpenRefine.